# Extracting multiple nested JSON keys at a time

Tags: python, json

How do I go about extracting more than one JSON key at a time given this script - the script cycles through a list of message ids and extracts the JSON response. I only want to extract certain keys from the response.

```
import urllib3
import json
import csv
from progressbar import ProgressBar
import time

pbar = ProgressBar()
base_url = 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/mailbox/mailMessages/'
fields = {"include_body": "1", "api_token": "token"}

json_arr = []
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
with open('ten.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    for x in pbar(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')):
            r = http.request('GET', base_url + "".join(x), fields=fields)
            mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
            json_arr.append(mails['data']['from'][0]['id'])

print(json_arr)
```

This works as intended. But I want to do the following.

```
json_arr.append(mails(['data']['from'][0]['id'],['data']['to'][0]['id'])
```

Which results in TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Can you please share a small sample of what your `mails` variable looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean:

```
json_arr.append(mails['data']['from'][0]['id'])
json_arr.append(mails['data']['to'][0]['id'])
```

Comment: Ah that fixed it. This works and just extracts the values into the JSON. How do I assign them to the correct keys in `json_arr = []` ? could you point me in the direction of the method doing this?

Comment: `json_arr` is a list. There are no keys in a list.

Answer (score 0):

The answer already posted looks good but I'll share the one-liner equivalent, using `extend()` instead of `append()`:

```
json_arr.extend([mails['data']['from'][0]['id'], mails['data']['to'][0]['id']])
```